# #05919769 Redirection loop when enabling SSL for Custom Domains

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl

I have 2 Google Apps for Work domains, I needed to change the billing for the apps domains and the apps team required me to delete the domains and recreate them. 
    After I deleted the Google for Works domains and recreated them I created an app on Google App Engine, I configured the app to serve at a custom domain and the app is currently serving via HTTP.
    I need the app to serve via HTTPS so I began configuring SSL for my custom domain.
    When I try to activate SSL for my custom domain in the Google apps for work admin panel I enter my "App Engine Application ID" into the "Security > Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains and click "Enable SSL for App Engine Applications" I am redirected to "https://appengine.google.com/start" which ends in a message:

"The webpage at https://appengine.google.com/start has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer."

- Cookies have been cleared
- reproducible on multiple browsers OS/machines - Linux/Chromebook etc.
- reproducible after removing the owner and adding them again
- reproducible after removing the App completely from the Admin Console  and re-adding it
- issue persists for more than 24 hours

I did a screen sharing session with the Google for Works support team and also provided a HAR file but they were unable to solve the issue.

Please can someone have a look at this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and https://appengine.google.com/start without this process? Is Cloud Projects or App Engine enabled in your domain?

Comment: Daniel, I am able to access console.developers.google.com/project and view my 3 projects which all have billing enabled. App engine is enabled and the app is deployed and serving. I cannot access appengine.google.com/start  at all, it always ends in a redirect loop.

Comment: The address https://appengine.google.com/start just redirects to https://appengine.google.com/ for me with a single redirect. I recently enabled SSL for custom domains on one of my applications and experience this redirect when I enabled SSL for App Engine in the domain control screen. Sorry. Perhaps check where the page is trying to redirect you with something like Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: appengine.google.com/start does redirect to appengine.google.com, It used to work before I had to delete my domain. I think the issue is that when my account was recreated it was assigned a new numeric ID in Google's database and for example I had to in the past have the Google Domains team manually assign the newly assigned numeric ID to my account/project data. I believe this is what needs to be done with my app engine account and my domain.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to provide and update in case someone else ran into this issue.
This is what worked for me:

Rename the username temporarily in the Google for Works admin panel, log out and log back in with the new username.

Then enter "App Engine Application ID" into the "Security > Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains and click "Enable SSL for App Engine Applications".

You should now get redirected to the "Enable SSL for this app" page in the Google developer's console(classic view"). Accept license agreement and Enable SSL.

Now go back to the Google for Works Admin Panel and rename the user back to the original username, log out and log back in.

Browse back to "Security > Advanced settings > SSL for Custom Domains" and you should be able to see an association of the app id to your billing account in the billing status. Further down click "Configure SSL Certificates" and there you can upload the certificates.

If the "Configure SSL Certificates" button is grayed out and you see an error:
 "has insufficient budget to add additional SSL resources. Increase the application's daily budget to be able to allocate VIPs or SNI certificate slots."

Go to the SNI section of the page and "INCREASE SNI CERTIFICATE SLOTS BY 5 ($0.00 A MONTH)"

The grayed out "Configure SSL Certificates" button is now usable and you can now proceed to  uploading your SSL certificate and private key.

I hope this helps someone